# Fungus blocking fish from eliminating

Tags: health, aquarium, fish

I recently acquired fungus in one of my tanks (from what I can tell I can see 3 fish with signs of it and one who has it the worst). I took the three and put them in a hospital tank to try to contain spreading, but am treating both. The worst of the three has a ring of the fungus around his gut right where most females have the gravid spot. He is still eating and eliminating, BUT instead of his poo being able to drag behind him and fall off it's stuck in the fungus and is wrapping around his body as it grows. I'm concerned with this happening he will lose the ability to eliminate, and stop eating or die from it (if the fungal infection doesn't kill him). I've seen people pick up larger fish with non latex gloves, for wound care and breeding purposes, but I try my best to put my hands in the tanks as little as possible, and never intend to  touch any of my fish. I am wondering if I can use my hands to rub part of the fuzzy off?

Ive treated sick fish for people over the years, wether it be my own, at a pet store, or friends and  haven't experienced THIS as a specific issue. I know this sounds like a strange or stupid question for most people, but I want his healing to be as smooth as possible and increase his chances of living. It's only been 24 hours since I started treatment, and was hoping to see enough improvement that he could poo like a normal fish. I added a different texture of plant to the hospital tank to encourage him to rub against and aquarium salt for general, Gill and fin health. If I can't rub some off, are there any additional recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the fungus off with your hands will not likely remove the fungus cells, and doing so may further stress the fish out. I apologize to have to say this, but if medicine doesn't work, it may be too late.